# Getting ICMP message content at application level via unprivileged sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, icmp

Is it possible to obtain the content of received `ICMP` messages via unprivileged sockets on Linux systems ?

I'm interested in knowing if it is possible to do so with `UDP` `DGRAM` sockets, `TCP` `STREAM` sockets and/or `ICMP` `DGRAM` sockets.

1. **`TCP` sockets**

I know that `AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP` sockets can obtain feedback on the outcome of a `connect()` via return values such as `ENETUNREACH`, `ETIMEDOUT` or such.  What I want is the actual entire `ICMP` message (the whole packet) by any means (create an other socket, ...) except sudo and setuid (no `raw` sockets).

2. **`UDP` sockets**

I know that you can set the `IP_RECVERR` `IP_PROTO`-level option to `AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP` sockets, but not to `STREAM` sockets. This option allows to call `recvmsg()` with the `MSG_ERRQUEUE` flag set in order to receive a `sock_extended_err` structure containing the `ICMP` error. Does it works default or do i have to specify which `ICMP` message i want to get passed (i.e.:via `ICMP_FILTER` socket options) ?

3. **`ICMP` sockets**

I also know that since ~2010, Linux systems allows `AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_ICMP` sockets to send a few `ICMP` messages for ping purposes (I don't care about sending `ICMP`) and to receive some (which type/code i don't know). But it looks like it's not enabled by default and need root permission to be activated, which is forbidden. Is it possible to use those to receive `ICMP` messages, and which messages ?

4. **Additional Informations**

I precise that I am asking this for Linux kernel >=2.6.x and IPv4. The `ICMP` messages I want to retreive are *most importantly* ttl-expired and *if possible* dest/port/host/network-unreach. I cannot run the program as root nor setuid root it, therefore `RAW` sockets are forbidden. I don't need to retreive the `IP` layer that encaspulate the `ICMP` messages.

Comment: This is not 100% duplicate, but quite close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914568/read-icmp-payload-from-a-recvmsg-with-msg-errqueue-flag.

Comment: [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) is at a lower level than both UDP and TCP, so no you can't use UDP or TCP for ICMP.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is at a different level of abstraction, but it does not mean that the information cannot be transmitted between the 2 (udp stack to application).

Comment: @user590028 Thanks, this should do it for point 2.